# Laptop won't boot from Windows 7 dvd

Tags: windows-7, boot, dvd, livecd

I have a Lenovo Y560 with dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7.
After some time Windows 7 refused to boot from HDD (stacked at Starting Windows).
Ubuntu is running fine.

I decided to re-install Windows 7, but computer wont boot from my DVD (also stacked at Starting Windows). DVD if 100% fine, works on other machine (also in virtualbox on Ubuntu). However I can boot live linux dvd.

Any idea where seems to be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is it the Upgrade version of Windows 7, or the full version?

Comment: It is full version.

Comment: I don't know, but I wonder if something changed hardware-wise and Windows 7 is having a hard time with it. Any chance you can get into Safe Mode? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7

Comment: No chance. Always gets stacked. Only Linux available.

Answer (score 1):

Matter resolved.
All I had to do was take out laptop battery (while laptop was turned on, nasty turn off).

I was able to boot from DVD, now I am answering my own question from new Windows :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ISO, you can use the Microsoft ISO to USB tool and boot to USB instead.